# Can past participle mean noun without 'the'?

Tags: grammar

1. It is far from achieved.

Can the word 'achieved' act as noun(achieved thing) without 'the'?

Comment: Why do you think that "achieved" has to be a noun?  Why do you think an adjective can't go there?

Comment: @stangdon perhaps because the learner thinks that a prepositional  phrase requires a noun (which seems a good assumption to me).

Comment: @AlanCarmack - Such assumptions can lead one *from bad to worse*.  :^)

Answer (score 2):

The idiom "far from ____" (meaning "very much not ____") can take either a noun phrase:

> He's far from **a giant**, but he's tall enough for this.

or a predicative adjective:

> It's far from **impossible**, but even so, it's not something you see every day.

or a participle:

> Far from **conspiring together**, there's reason to think they'd never even heard of each other!

In your case, *achieved* is either a participle or a participial adjective. Either way, it's not a noun, and does not mean "an achieved thing".